# Why don't we get VIBGYOR instead of white light?

Tags: optics, visible-light, everyday-life, atmospheric-science, dispersion

Why doesn't the atmosphere disperse white light from the Sun like a prism as air is a dispersive medium? If it really did so, shouldn't we be receving the 7 colours separately instead of one?

Answer (score 2):

It does, but the effect is very small. See, the Sun disk appears raised only by about half a degree at the horizon, where refraction effect is the most visible. And dispersion is even smaller, so the colored edge of the Sun disk is undetectable by unaided eye.

See [here](http://www.atoptics.co.uk/atoptics/gf15.htm) for a related discussion of green rim vs green flash.

Answer (score 0):

Blue light has a shorter wavelength. Light with shorter wavelengths `bumps' into the atoms in the atmosphere more often is therefore scattered more often than lightwaves with a longer wavelength. This phenomenon is known as [Rayleigh scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering). As a result, the sky disperses the blue light in all directions while the green, yellow and red light waves from the sun can for a large part avoid bumping into the atoms in the atmosphere.

[image]

Comment: That was not what I asked. Make a small slit on a piece of paper and send sunlight through it onto a screen. It does not show a dispersed pattern, but simply white light.

Comment: Ow... But there is no 'interface' between outer space and the atmosphere. The atmosphere becomes exponentially thinner as you go up into the air. There is thus not an interface at which diffraction would take place.

Comment: So is it right to believe that dispersion takes place only at a solid interface?